# MySQL - Working Back Through Multiple Tables by FK

Tags: mysql, relationship

I have a database which isn't of my own creation. I need to extract some specific data from it but I'm struggling to get my head around how to get the data back without doing multiple queries and looping over the result set in my code. I've looked around at other questions but haven't been able to get very far.

My data structure is (very condensed with non-relevant rows and columns omitted):

```
MyDb.Source
+--------+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| ID     | SOURCE_TYPE |  URL                                 |
+--------+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| 10     |          3  |  https://en.wikipedia.org            |
+--------+-------------+--------------------------------------+

MyDb.Resource
+--------+------------+--------------------------------------+
| ID     | SOURCE_FK  |  IDENTIFIER                          |
+--------+------------+--------------------------------------+
| 1      |         10 |  All_Saints_Church,_Marple           |
+--------+------------+--------------------------------------+

MyDb.Item_Base
+--------+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| ID     | RESOURCE_FK |  ITEM_TITLE                          |
+--------+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| 55     |          1  |  All Saints Church, Marple           |
+--------+-------------+--------------------------------------+

MyDb.Item
+--------+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| ID     | BASE_FK     |  ITEM_DESCRIPTION                    |
+--------+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| 120    |         55  |  Foo bar                             |
+--------+-------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Source - Resource is 1 to many.

Resource - Base is 1 to 1.

Item_Base - Item is 1 to 1.

**What am I trying to do?**

I want as few queries as possible to work back from `MyDb.Source` to find all items related to it. The only information I have in my hand is the `ID` for the source, which is 10. I want to end up with a result set of `Item.ID` which contains only those where `Source.ID` is 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just inner join the four tables together in a single query.  This should be safe, because in order for a relationship to exist between a source and an item, the latter must be reachable via a key relationship.

```
SELECT
    t1.ID AS source_id,
    t4.*
FROM Source t1
INNER JOIN Resource t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.SOURCE_FK
INNER JOIN Item_Base t3
    ON t2.ID = t3.RESOURCE_FK
INNER JOIN Item t4
    ON t3.ID = t4.BASE_FK
WHERE
    t1.ID = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `INNER JOIN`s in your query. Then it's possible in one simple query:

```
SELECT 
  i.ID 
FROM
  Source s
  INNER JOIN Resource r
    ON s.ID = r.SOURCE_FK
  INNER JOIN Item_Base b
    ON r.ID = b.RESOURCE_FK
  INNER JOIN Item i
    ON b.ID = i.BASE_FK
WHERE
  s.ID = 10
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html and http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx for more info and examples relating to joins and how to use them.

Comment: Many thanks for the links. I was trying to use joins before but not in that way. I'll give it a shot next time I'm at my PC.